# HttpSession Java EE

Tags: java-ee-7

Everyone!

So I have a little problem with httpsession and I don't know how to fixed it. here is the problem.

I have  a Class Person which has a`set<Product>` and I set that class person into
the request.getSession like this.

String email = getRequest().getParameter("email");
String credential = getRequest().getParameter("credential");

```
    validEmail(email);
    validCredential(credential);

    if(existError()){
        setValues(email, credential);;
        forward(login);
        return;
    }


    PersonService ps = serviceFactory.getService(PersonService.class);

    boolean success = ps.validatePasswordAndEmail(email, credential);

    if(success){

    Person person = ps.getPersonByEmail(email);                     

    getSession().setAttribute("person", person);    here you can see the object person into the session     

    forward("/packed.jsp");

    }else{

        addError("Email or Credential is not valid!");
        setValues(email, credential);
        forward(login);
        return;
    }
```

After that if the users put their correct information they will come to another
file called packed.jsp and they are logged.

My problem is when I edit a product's person who are logged into the system. let me show my code here

The page called packed.jsp has a buttom where the person who are logged click
and then he comes to this servlet below

```
public class EditProductAction extends Action {

private String editProduct = "/edit_product.jsp";
private String packed = "/packed.jsp";

@Override
public void process() throws Exception {        


    Integer id = Integer.parseInt(getRequest().getParameter("id"));
    String brand = getRequest().getParameter("brand");
    String model = getRequest().getParameter("model");
    String name = getRequest().getParameter("name");
    String quantity = getRequest().getParameter("quantity");
    String color = getRequest().getParameter("color");
    String info = getRequest().getParameter("info");


    ProductService ps = serviceFactory.getService(ProductService.class); 


    Product product = ps.getProductByID(id);

    if(name == null){       
        getRequest().setAttribute("product",product);
        forward(editProduct);
        return;
    }

    product.setBrand(brand);
    product.setModel(model);
    product.setName(name);
    product.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(quantity));
    product.setColor(color);
    product.setInfo(info);

    ps.update(product); 


   getResponse().sendRedirect(getRequest().getContextPath()+packed);


}
```

}

As you can see everything works fine but when I come back to the page packed.jsp
it doesn't show the product modyfied but in the database works fine, I mean the product has been modyfied. here packed.jsp

```
<div class="mainDiv">
<table border="1px" width="80%">
    <tr>
        <th>BRAND</th>
        <th>MODEL</th>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>QUANTITY</th>
        <th>COLOR</th>
        <th>INFO</th>
        <th>EDIT</th>
        <th>DELETE</th>
    </tr>
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${empty person.products}">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="8" align="center"><span>You don't have any product yet!</span></td>
            </tr>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <c:forEach var="p" items="${person.products}">

                <c:url var="urlDel" value="servlet">
                    <c:param name="id" value="${p.id}" />
                </c:url>

                <c:url var="urlEdit" value="EditProduct.action">
                    <c:param name="id" value="${p.id}" />
                </c:url>

                <tr>
                    <td>${p.brand}</td>
                    <td>${p.model}</td>
                    <td>${p.name}</td>
                    <td>${p.quantity}</td>
                    <td>${p.color}</td>
                    <td>${p.info}</td>
                    <td><a href="${urlEdit}"><img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/edit.png"></a></td>
                    <td><a href="${urlDel}"><img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/delete.png"></a></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</table>
```

I would like to change the product and then when I back to packed.jsp I want to see the product modyfied.  Thank you very much everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by creating another class with those objects and then put it the session. It works.